Permutation and combination and Combinatorics
In how many ways can we select exactly k objects out of n groups of identical objects of different sizes. For example there are 3 bananas, 4 apples and 5 mangoes. Fruit of each kind is identical. In how many ways can we select exactly 2 fruits, and exactly 3 fruits. Pls help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please clarify: you say "identical objects of different sizes",but it seems that size is not relevant. With your example $(B1,B2,B3,A1,A2,A3,A4,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5)$, do you consider that $(B1, A1)$ and $(B1,A2)$ are similar ? Last question : what have you done to try to solve this exercize ?
